# Django - Multiple instances of same form class in one view

Tags: python, django, forms, post, django-forms

In the context of Django Forms, I've seen many discussions of handling different kinds of `form`s on the same page (eg `AForm` and `BForm` on the same page), but I'm trying to figure how to handle multiple instances of the same `form` class on a page.

I am able to display the forms alright, but I don't know how to handle them when the forms are `POST`ed.

I've tried using `Formset`s as well, and have the same issue (can display, but don't know how to handle `POST`).

So here's my question: let's say I'm displaying several instances of the **same** `Form` class on a page. How would I go about handling the `POST` data when these forms are submitted?

Edit:

Problem with `formset` is that I have a custom Form and have found it difficult to use `formset` to handle `POST` data.

Edit 2 - providing more details given @neverwalkaloner's response.

Here's my form class:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, question, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
    self.fields['answers'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                            widget=RadioSelect)

    self.fields['answers'].label = question.content
```

I'm creating different forms with a prefix like so: `form = QuestionForm(question=question, prefix=prefix)`

Then, handling POST data like so: `form = QuestionForm(data=request.POST, question=question, prefix=prefix)`

However, the forms do not bind with the above approach :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) argument to initialize multiple forms in your view:

```
mother = PersonForm(request.POST, prefix="mother")
father = PersonForm(request.POST, prefix="father")

return render(request, 'some_template.html', {
    'mother': mother,
    'father': father,
})
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! That is exactly the thought I had too, but I'm not able to get the form to bind with this approach. I'll add some more details about my `Form` and the binding logic in the question, would be great if you could provide some feedback.

Comment: @John `PersonForm(request.POST, prefix="mother")` should work fine. How do you render form in template?

Comment: Here's the rendering code from the template. I also added more details about the `Form` subclass in the OP
`questions` is the list of forms: 
`{% for question in questions %} 
<tr><td> {{ question.as_p }} </td></tr>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: @John one small comment in form's `__init__` I suppose it should be `super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)`. You missed data argument.

Comment: Ah, you're a life-saver :) Binding now works as expected - thank you!